# windows 8 compatablity issues with netflix

Tags: windows-8, drm, netflix

Has anyone encountered the DRM error with netflix in Windows 8 and found a fix for it. I consistently get prompted to install silverlight, and am informed of its successful installation, yet like a continuous loop Im asked to install it again @ the beginning of streaming a movie.

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Wait are we talking about the app or netflix on the browser here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try and seeing if going to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\PlayReady and deleting mspr.hds solves your problem?

Credit: [TechNet Answers](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/W8ITProPreRel/thread/a971d9e2-1eb6-472f-9c9e-4a56408d16f5)

Comment: Yeah that doesen't seem to be having much of an effect.

Comment: Nope after I did a reboot it works now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to:

- Close all Chrome windows (and any other browsers)
- Check my systray and right-click any Chrome icons and click Exit
- Delete C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\PlayReady\mspr.hds
- Start Internet Explorer
- Login to Netflix, attempt to play a video, get the error at 20% after a long freeze
- Close IE
- Delete mspr.hds again
- Open IE and try to play again, get another error at 98%
- Close IE and delete mspr.hds again
- Open IE one last time and play

Then it worked, in both IE and Chrome.